# programmatically fill in all the required fields in a webform, then submit manually

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I want to programmatically fill in all the required fields in the webform at

http://www.whitehouse.gov/contact/submit-questions-and-comments

except for the final challenge question (which must be answered manually and then the form will be submitted manually).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Alter the form before it's rendered:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Set different default value for that field.